# how to know which dependencies file require what minSdkVersion in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I am using many dependencies in my android studio.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.0.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.2.+'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.+'
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.+'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.+'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.+'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.+'
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'

compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

I am using `minSdkVersion 10`  But now I am getting error as

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 13 declared in library
```

After increasing minSdkVersion to 13 it will work. But I want to know which dependencies file is required vminSdkVersion 13.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
this one!

Answer (score 2):

More generally, you can find this information out in the manifest merger report. This will show up in `build/outputs/apk` of whatever your app's module is (e.g., `app/`).

For example, here is the `uses-sdk` snippet from the manifest merger report for a demo app for one of my libraries:

```
uses-sdk
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:7:2
MERGED from com.commonsware.cwac:colormixer:0.6.1:7:5
MERGED from RichTextEditor:richedit:unspecified:7:5
    android:targetSdkVersion
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:9:3
    android:minSdkVersion
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:8:3
```

This says that it pulled in values from three sources:

- the demo module's own manifest
- the manifest published in the `com.commonsware.cwac:colormixer` artifact
- the manifest published in the `:richedit` module

And, in this case, it pulled the values from the demo module's own manifest, at the line numbers shown.